# how do i make my website accessible from the internet without a static ip and from a virtual machine?

Tags: networking, dns, vmware, server, router

I have windows 8 host and i have installed ubuntu 14.10 server as a virtual machine in vmware. i have installed LAMP server and i am trying to host a website from it. i have created a virtual host. my website is accessible in the host machine when i go to the address 192.168.0.106.

my router info:

**LAN**

IP Address :192.168.0.1

**INTERNET**

IP Address :**10.30.XXX.XXX**

"what is my ip" in google: **113.XXX.XXX.XXX**

how do i make my website accessible from the internet ? I know it is a dumb question, but i tried searching everywhere and could not get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you can connect to the site from the host machine, it does not matter that it is in a VM.

You say that you can connect to your site via: `192.168.0.106` on the LAN. You need to forward connections to your WAN address (`113.193.56.198`) to your LAN address (`192.168.0.106`). You can do this in most router settings in a section called Port forwarding. Use port `80` if you're hitting the LAN IP from a browser and you don't have to add a port after the address like `http:\\192.168.0.106:1234`. Otherwise, use whatever port you like.

Once you get that working, it is a good idea to use a dynamic DNS service, which will connect your IP to a domain name and update the connection whenever your WAN IP changes. This way, instead of using the WAN IP in a browser, you can use your domain name and it should always work. But that's not your first problem. First get it working with the WAN IP by itself. Once you've got that working, get some DynDNS.

EDIT

If you think it should be working but can't figure out why it isn't, use a tool like nmap/zenmap to scan your WAN and LAN IPs. That will help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect your whatismyip result. The IP that you got with whatismyip is what you should type in to get to your router. If your router is set up to forward requests to `http:\\113.193.56.198` to a machine on your LAN such as `192.168.0.106` then it will work.

Comment: What kind of router do you have?

Comment: it is a d-link DIR-605L wireless router

Comment: @user1101611 Try this for setting up port forwarding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu-guHdg8Sw The name doesn't matter. the IP Address should be `192.168.0.106`, and ALL of the port fields should be 80. Does that work?

Comment: sorry to reply late, i set up the port forwarding as you mentioned, but when i visit http://10.30.195.241/  i am able to see my site, but NOT with http://113.193.56.198/.   also , even with "10.30.195.241", i am not able to  access my site from a different ISP, i tried from my mobile internet, but i am not able to access it, probably because my isp has not provided me with public ip...so is there a workaround , like dns service ?

Comment: @user1101611 When I visit http://113.193.56.198/, I see your web page. :) Congrats! Now you just need to set up dynamic dns on your router with a 3rd party dns provider like dyndns or no-ip. There are instructions for how to do that on most of their sites.

Comment: i just inserted my ip in godaddy, and my site http://legitscience.com/ is working. i can access it using proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

A [DynDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) should do the job!
It will automatically renew your dynamic ip address. All you need is; a tool that runs on your server with website.

Search for it on google, and you'll find a solution. Btw: there are, Free and paid solutions.

EDIT: by the way, your router requires additionally some [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to make your website accessible from outside. Even with the DynDNS stuff installed.

Just to give you some indications.